# chown and chmod for folder only (recursively) on hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, chmod, chown

I want to chown and chmod on hdfs (recursively) but only for the folder.
In Linux we can do it using `find`

https://superuser.com/questions/91935/how-to-recursively-chmod-all-directories-except-files

https://gist.github.com/bzerangue/3b210b009e8d934b4a68

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

When I try the same in HDFS

```
hdfs dfs -find /path/to/base/dir -type d -print0
```

I get an error

```
find: Unexpected argument: -type
```

Hadoop version : Hadoop 3.1.1.7.1.7.0-551

Note: I actually also tried in Hadoop 2.6.0 and got `-find: Unknown command` ,
so I think I need to use Hadoop version 3+.

Is there any equivalent in Hadoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should work for both Hadoop 2 and 3.

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /path/to/base/dir/ | grep "^d"
```

As a bonus, one can extend the regex used in grep beyond simple "directories only" (`^d`) to further filter the results.

Comment: thanks, but I think the main problem about chmod and chown still not solved yet, but I got the idea to use it in bash script

Comment: update: I just try `hdfs dfs -chmod 755 $(hdfs dfs -ls -R /path/to/base/dir/ | grep "^d" | awk '{print $8}')` and it works